# How to config spring cloud oauth2 in docker container

Tags: spring, docker, spring-cloud, microservices, oauth-2.0

I met some problems with micro-spring-docker , i think maybe the sso token-url is not correct.

The demo https://github.com/keryhu/micro-oauth2-docker

In local computer , sso service and auth-service works fine .

But not  in docker container ,

> the problem is that redirecting to auth-server Timeout .

**SSO(pc-gateway service) application.yml:**

```
security:
  user:
    password: none
  oauth2:
    client:
      accessTokenUri: http://${AUTHSERVER_PORT_9999_TCP_ADDR:localhost}:9999/uaa/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://${AUTHSERVER_PORT_9999_TCP_ADDR:localhost}:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
eureka:
  image: eureka:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  container_name: eureka
  hostname: eureka
  ports:
   - "8761:8761"

configserver:
  image: config-server:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  container_name: configserver
  hostname: configserver
  links:
    - eureka
  ports:
    - "8888:8888"

authserver:
  image: auth-server:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  container_name: authserver
  hostname: authserver
  links:
    - eureka
    - configserver
  ports:
    - "9999:9999"

pcgateway:
  image: pc-gateway:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  container_name: pcgateway
  hostname: pcgateway
  links:
    - eureka
    - configserver
    - authserver
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
```

After starting in docker container :

http://192.168.99.100:8761/ showing :

```
Instances currently registered with Eureka
Application   AMIs     Availability Zones   Status
AUTHSERVER   n/a(1)           (1)           UP (1) - authserver:authserver:9999
CONFIGSERVER n/a(1)           (1)           UP (1) - configserver:configserver:8888
PCGATEWAY    n/a(1)           (1)           UP (1) - pcgateway:pcgateway:8080
```

But when open the auth page: http://192.168.99.100:8080

It should be redirected to  auth-server login page , but it opened Timeout ， the Address Bar is:

```
http://172.17.0.4:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize?client_id=clientapp&redirect_uri=http://192.168.99.100:8080/login&response_type=code&state=cdXhfg
```

I don't know why , maybe the above sso tokenurl is not correct . How to resolve ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `172.17.0.4` IP-address is the IP-address of the `authserver` container on the **internal** (container-container) network, which is *not* reachable from outside the docker host (Virtual Machine).

This may be tricky, because (in this case) you need to provide the IP-address of the Virtual Machine that docker runs on, which may *change*, and definitely will be different in production.

If you change `${AUTHSERVER_PORT_9999_TCP_ADDR:localhost}` to `192.168.99.100`, it should work.

I suggest to make the IP-address (or domain) configurable using an environment-variable that you provide in the docker-compose.yml, so something like:

```
${DOMAIN_NAME:192.168.99.100}
```

Which defaults to the "standard" IP-address of the Virtual Machine. In production you can then pass the actual domain-name, or IP-address of the server your project runs on.

> Note that the "link" environment variables are marked deprecated, and only will
>   be used on the default (bridge) network. The new linking feature won't create
>   these variables, but you can simply link to other containers by *name*. See
>   https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/#linking-containers-in-user-defined-networks

Comment: sorry , I'm a newer.  I have not resolved completely . I write: `domainname: 192.168.99.100` in docker-compose.yml by a  line ,  in spring application.yml  write  `http://${domainname:localhost}:9999/uaa/oauth/token`  ?

Comment: you can start with changing your config to `accessTokenUri: http://192.168.99.100:9999/uaa/oauth/token` to see if that works, and work from that (the environment variables solution) see environment variables in the docker-compose documentation; https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment

Comment: thanks,it works ,i write  environment: `DOMAIN_NAME: 192.168.99.100`
     in docker-compose.yml ,and `http://${domain.name:localhost}:9999/uaa`   in application.yml